# TypeScript: Recursively map two objects of same shape to each other

Tags: typescript, types

I have some data coming in from some `source` regularly. It's just nested objects of numbers. IE:

```
{
 a: 1,
 b: {
  c: 2,
  d: 3.1,
 },
}
```

I want to put all those data into a bunch of TimeSeries objects of the same shape:

```
const timeSeries = {
 a: new TimeSeries(),
 b: {
  c: new TimeSeries(),
  d: new TimeSeries(),
 },
}
```

And then, on each `'update'` event, call `TimeSeries.append(time, data)` for each new data point:

```
timeSeries.a.append(time, data.a);
timeSeries.b.c.append(time, data.b.c);
timeSeries.b.d.append(time, data.b.d);
```

Of course the goal is to do this automatically when `data` gets more complicated.

So far, I've got this. The underlying JavaScript works, I just can't get the types to work properly, hence the TypeScript question. Any idea?

```
// I do know what this shape is at compile time.
// I even manually initialize an instance of this in one part of the code. I just don't want to have to copy that whole block for the TimeSeries. But maybe I need to...
type Data = {
 a: number;
 b: {
  c: number;
  d: number;
 }
}

// Some other library that I'm using. This is all you need to know to replicate functionality.
interface TimeSeries {
 append(time: number, value: number): void;
}

// Helper function
function isNestedValues<V, T extends {}>(value: V | T): value is T {
  return typeof value === 'object';
}

// This type mapping seems to work well
type MappedTimeSeries<T extends {}> = {
  [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends {} ? MappedTimeSeries<T[P]> : TimeSeries;
};

// Our mapping of time series.
// It is partial because it starts empty until the first bit of data comes in and fills out the object.
// I don't want other things to try to use the TimeSeries before they're ready.
export const timeSeries = {} as Partial<MappedTimeSeries<Data>>;

// Would be nice to improve the strict typing of this being a number
function updateTimeSeriesRecursive<T extends {}>(time: number, o: T, ts: MappedTimeSeries<T>) {
  for (const x in o) {
    type P = Extract<keyof T, string>; // I had this in there at one point. Forget why it was useful lol.
    if (isNestedValues(o[x])) {
      // Initialize TimeSeries{} on first set of data
      if (!ts[x]) ts[x] = {} as MappedTimeSeries<typeof o[x]>; // I know. `typeof o[x]` is runtime, being used in compile time context. One of the things to figure out.

      updateTimeSeriesRecursive(time, o[x], ts[x]);
    } else {
      // Initialize actual TimeSeries on first set of data
      if (!ts[x]) ts[x] = new TimeSeries();

      (ts[x] as TimeSeries).append(time, o[x]);
    }
  }
}

source.on('update', time: number, (data: Data) => {
  updateTimeSeriesRecursive(time, state, timeSeries);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a perfect solution in my opinion, since some of the type manipulation you're doing is still outside of the compiler's abilities to follow, thus requiring you to do [type assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) or the equivalent (such as single call-signature [overloaded functions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads)).  Here's one way I might proceed:

```
type DataConstraint<T> = { [K in keyof T]: DataConstraint<T[K]> | number }

type MappedTimeSeries<T extends DataConstraint<T>> = {
    [K in keyof T]?: T[K] extends DataConstraint<T[K]> ? MappedTimeSeries<T[K]> : TimeSeries }

const timeSeries: MappedTimeSeries<Data> = {};

function updateTimeSeriesRecursive<T extends DataConstraint<T>>(
    time: number, o: T, ts: MappedTimeSeries<T>
): void;
function updateTimeSeriesRecursive(
    time: number, o: DataConstraint<any>, ts: MappedTimeSeries<any>
): void {
    for (const x in o) {
        const ox = o[x];
        if (typeof ox === "number") {
            const tsx = ts[x] = ts[x] || new TimeSeries();
            (tsx as TimeSeries).append(time, ox);
        } else {
            const tsx = ts[x] = ts[x] || {};
            updateTimeSeriesRecursive(time, ox, tsx as MappedTimeSeries<DataConstraint<any>>);
        }
    }
}
```

That's pretty close to what you have already.  Notable changes:

- the `DataConstraint<T>` type represents your constraint that the properties of a `Data`-like type should be either `number` or other `DataConstraint` objects.
- You can constrain `MappedTimeSeries<T>` so that `T` must conform to `DataConstraint<T>`.  One issue with your original definition was the conditional type check `T[K] extends {} ? ...` , which is true even when `T[K]` is `number` (since the empty type `{}` matches everything but `null` and `undefined`).  At the very least it should be `T[K] extends object ? ...`  (which doesn't match primitives like  `number`), and the version with `T[K] extends DataConstraint<T[K]> ? ...`  works.
- The `updateTimeSeriesRecursive()` function has a single call-signature overload which is generic, much like your original definition (with the addition of the `DataConstraint` constraint), and an implementation signature which is not generic, instead using the wider types `DataConstraint<any>` and `MappedTimeSeries<any>`.  The compiler can't really narrow generic type parameters via control flow analysis (see [microsoft/TypeScript#24085](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24085)), so having the implementation be generic doesn't do much for you.

There's a bit more but those are the main pieces.  It works for me when I make a function like

```
function doStuff(time: number, data: Data) {
    updateTimeSeriesRecursive(time, data, timeSeries); // okay
}

doStuff(1, { a: 1, b: { c: 2, d: 3 } });
doStuff(2, { a: 2, b: { c: 4, d: 4 } });
doStuff(3, { a: 3, b: { c: 6, d: 5 } });
doStuff(4, { a: 4, b: { c: 8, d: 6 } });
```

[Link to code with example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHZBvAUMg5OALmRAFcBbAI2gG59DrS9C3kFSKb7H3kAJlyq0oDNgF9cU3AgA2cAM6LkAFWCUIAZWjAIK1oQAOUYADcMKRbv0tkYDRGE8oAGmQW55J2RHRkEgDaALrIALzIIeKEcEZGECACABQOms6i7p7e6dAAlDh87GAAFsCKAHTWpvrlRuSKxUnY9o6ZcF4oErmFEtEEYAD2WmCmIADmSfmG-FAQYORQIMgARKpay8gA1PalFVV6FZSxSWbhAHwrSaqkG9tm5ako28sAajdbHuVZTyu5y7nlABWA1ASWW7n+fQC0lwuDAAE94mgMHAAMIDECKEZwUBgAA8qguEWagQA0shQMgANYQeEDGBqYKkdCYdGY7G4glk4IXAA+vhc0LhiJQAFlYvEBOpNDpqooCcgIAAPSCJFQstEYrFQHHgAlnIkFNhkilLGl0hmqYIAflIqm5ipVCQE6pRbO1uvx9tJPOQ1uQ4riECljllBy5PoudtDNhUMgQWrALRlsdIgcl0u0sbxGsN2F6sJg5BACAcGOQ5CMAksmbD+gAShAEAtFOYIArlaqXcjWYmdZzCWckoVHjk3MgBnb3GBFGmJcHa9nCbhcqQzCCBAwiyWy0tK9XIIu5Y3m1BW2YIMO2KOBRkJ8y3X3PXi4CB4Wdp7OA-OQym5S+3zOFc1w3I1CBgAYoGQJIE3ZZAlVNCcpkKNhYKxCcEIiAZAiVYIoTYYAGRSEV6Qw8IwgiZZuFEf4wP4VDE3sRRMKYnDQgiGc2OQXl+RACAAHc1BjOVJnw+iUmYogVCPA4AXnRIUlaDDcjEggJEVORrDo+iCDQpMZxYzjcPCVjjJ4nACx0th9xrYSDhPFs20UzR3AGJVPwQpRvyDX8s3-DV3Q5PVX3fM4VJQwgpEkGFcG3UtgHLAQhnmGAYGcnxqOgdwDxIHs4GQ6yq1sv97KbRyL3S7KUWnOz9BU5AAHoGonKk4HhGKkuGchUqSABGdxmly-rkGYHAOFIAAmbLSAAZgCAJws6lK0qmsbctW0bmk4ZAABZpt2+augYJburSmaBqIWb3E28bkAANn2gBWQ7FuS06kj2tbSE+m7toADn2u6XoYWQtQGOQIHKOQBgmAApLQAHkADlKhGUAxkI+F0rrRRcnC2ECdwIA)